Why is the specific heat capacity of water greater than that of ice?
My powerpoint at school says the following:

how can this make sense if the rate of temperature change is inversely proportional to the specific heat capacity, wouldn't that mean that the specific heat capacity of water should be smaller given its steeper gradient?

it makes sense physically though, water has a smaller number of neighbouring atoms so its more difficult to increase its temperature, therefore meaning it has a greater specific heat capacity

You are quite correct and the graph is wrong.
